# Return tuple or other C# type from ASP.NET Core MVC form to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the C# course I'm taking, today's lesson was adding another model to our ASP.NET actions to create new items in our database and interact with them. The exercise is a pizza shop, and today we're adding categories to the pizzas.

What we were taught today is that you'd make a top level ViewModel to send to the views that would contain both our original model, our pizzas, and a list of categories in order to show those to the user when adding, modifying or viewing pizzas.

I decided that I'd try with a tuple, as the less code I write, the cleaner I feel my exercise is, as there's less code to track. Unfortunately, this instead returned an error as ASP.NET cannot create a model without a parameterless constructor, such as System.Tuple

Is there any way I can avoid creating a top level viewmodel just for this case, and instead pass around multiple models (an object of class Pizza, and a list of every Category object in my database) to and from a view, as well as forms?

Below is the code for creating a new Pizza item that is giving me the error.

```cs
// ADD A NEW PIZZA
public IActionResult New() {
    using var db = new PizzasDbContext();
    Pizza emptyPizza = new();
    List<Category> categories = db.Categories.ToList();
    return View(new Tuple<Pizza, List<Category>>(emptyPizza, categories));
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult New(Tuple<Pizza, List<Category>> returnedTuple) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        using (var db = new PizzasDbContext()) {
            List<Category> categories = db.Categories.ToList();
            return View(new Tuple<Pizza, List<Category>>(returnedTuple.Item1, categories));
        }
    }

    using (var db = new PizzasDbContext()) {
        int modifications = db.AddPizza(returnedTuple.Item1);
        Console.WriteLine(modifications);
    }

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Below is the form I'm using to create new pizzas on my database

```
@model Tuple<Pizza, List<Category>>
@{
    Layout = "_Header";
}

<form asp-controller="Pizza" asp-action="New" method="post">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="container-fluid d-flex flex-column align-items-center my-3">
        <div class="row g-5 w-100">
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <label for="pizzaName" class="form-label">Nome</label>
                <input asp-for="Item1.Name" type="text" class="form-control" id="pizzaName" aria-describedby="pizzaNameHelp">
                <div id="pizzaNameHelp" class="form-text">Il nome della pizza</div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Item1.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <label for="pizzaImage" class="form-label">Link Immagine</label>
                <input asp-for="Item1.PictureUrl" type="text" class="form-control" id="pizzaImage" aria-describedby="pizzaImgHelp">
                <div id="pizzaImgHelp" class="form-text">Il link della pizza. Assicurati che punti ad un file .png or .jpg!</div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Item1.PictureUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <label for="pizzaPrice" class="form-label">Prezzo</label>
                <input asp-for="Item1.Price" type="number" step=".01" class="form-control" id="pizzaPrice" aria-describedby="pizzaImgHelp" lang="en-us">
                <div id="pizzaImgHelp" class="form-text">Il prezzo della pizza.</div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Item1.Price" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
                <label for="pizzaCategory" class="form-label">Categoria</label>
                <select asp-for="Item1.CategoryId" id="pizzaCategory" aria-describedby="pizzaCategoryHelp">
                    <option selected>Seleziona una categoria</option>
                    @foreach (Category category in Model.Item2) {
                        <option value="@category.Id">@category.Name</option>
                    }
                </select>
                <div id="pizzaCategoryHelp" class="form-text">La categoria della pizza.</div>
                <span asp-validation-for="Item1.CategoryId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
                <label for="pizzaDescription" class="form-label">Descrizione</label>
                <textarea asp-for="Item1.Description" type="text" class="form-control" id="pizzaDescription" placeholder="Descrivi in modo succoso la tua pizza"></textarea>
                <span asp-validation-for="Item1.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary m-3 align-self-baseline">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Don't get clever. Avoid tuples at this early stage, especially for view models. A clear, distinct model class will win out in maintainability. The first time you have to add a type parameter to all your `Tuple<...>` references, you'll get it.

Comment: @madreflection your comment doesn't answer my question :/
While maintainability is certainly important, this is the only stage where I could experiment with something like alternatives to a top level viewmodel that bundles my other models, so while I can, I'd like to get as clever as possible, specifically to try stuff out while still in formation.

Comment: You don't "return" anything from the view to the controller, you *post* to the controller. In a FORM post, form fields are matched to DTO properties by name. Tuples have no properties or names though, they have fields named `Item1` etc. The  name are only syntactic sugar that disappears after compilation

Comment: @ThomasYoussef the comment *did* answer the question. Don't do that, it doesn't work. If you want a one-line DTO, use a `record`. That only works well in .NET 6/7 though.

Comment: @madreflection I asked "How can I do this", not whether I should or not. I'm sorry, but again, I specifically want to experiment, regardless of the consequences, because at the moment it won't result in me getting fired from an actual job or punished severely. This is the right period to experiment, even though you think that I shouldn't.

Comment: Besides, where's the form that posts to this action, and how are its fields named? I doubt it has 5 fields all named `Item1`? How does this form manage to post *objects* instead of individual fields?

Comment: Just added the form itself to the original question, thanks for pointing that out. And I'm not posting objects anywhere, that was simply a mistake on my end with terminology

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are using `System.Tuple<..>` instead of the newer `System.ValueTuple<..>`? `ValueTuple` also has a parameterless constructor(since it's a struct) and has support for some [syntax sugar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).

Comment: @AmalK ASP.NET cannot create value types. I've tried it before, but I would get the same error.

Comment: You might be able to write a [Custom Model Binder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to bind to a `Tuple`. Though doing so would likely result in more code, and definitely result in more complex code, than just using a proper view model. You might also be able to pass a `FormCollection` to the `POST` action and read the form values manually. It'd be more code and more complex code than just using a view model though.

Comment: I know I'm not answering your question, but I suggest using public List<SelectListItem> PizzaCategorySelectItems;   Then you can just set <select ... asp-items="Model.PizzaCategorySelectItems" ....> and use a LINQ query to set text and values...  (category name, category id)  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.selectlistitem?view=aspnetcore-6.0